# Lisp: Collect multiple lists in loop

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp

I want to be able to collect multiple lists inside a loop.

I know this can be done without a loop, however I was wondering whether this would be possible with a loop as well. I'd like something like this:

```
  (loop for var in list
        (if (cond1 var)
            (if (cond2 var)
                collect into list1
                collect into list2))
        finally (list list1 list2))
```

I get the error that the `LOOP keyword is expected`, I guess the collect should be used right after a `when` or a `loop`. Is there any way to solve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

First, if you want to put normal Lisp code into the loop body, you need the `do` keyword. But you could use `do`'s `when` or `if` keywords instead.

Second, the `collect` keyword requires you to specify an expression to collect into the list, e.g. `collect var into list1`.

Third, you need to use `(return expression)` to return a value from the form in the `finally` clause.

```
  (loop for var in list
    when (cond1 var)
      if (cond2 var)
        collect var into list1
      else
        collect var into list2
    finally (return (list list1 list2)))
```

Comment: Both answers are great, but this is what I needed to make it all run! Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Believe it or not you have **too many parentheses**. `loop` has its own little sublanguage which is quite different from Common Lisp s-expressions.

```lisp
(loop :for var :in list
      :when (cond1 var)
        :if (cond2 var)
           :collect var :into list1
        :else
           :collect var :into list2
        :end
      :end
      :finally (return (list list1 list2)))
```

In addition I specify what to `:collect` and `:finally` just evaluates so you need to use `(return ...)` or else you can expect `nil`.

I use keywords for `loop` keywords to distinguish them from other symbols. It's just style. The indentation is of course ignored and just for readability, but `:end` isn't. However in this case both `:end` keywords are redundant since the `loop` is parsed correctly without them.

I'm by no means a `loop` wiz.. Every time I get something slightly complex I tend to use [Land of Lisp](http://www.landoflisp.com/)'s Periodic table or [Loop for black belts](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html), a chapter from [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/).

[image: Periodic table of Loop Macro]

Comment: Could you share the source of the "Periodic Table of the Loop Macro" please?

Comment: @Hellseher As I wrote  in my answer it's from the book  [Land of Lisp](http://www.landoflisp.com/). There is a PDF version on the Internet however as this is copyrighted work I don't think that would be considered fair use to put on SO. I own a copy and urge everyone interested to buy the book as it is a great work of art.